# Ext JS grid with grouping expand one row on click

Tags: grid, grouping, expand, extjs4.2

I have an Ext JS grid that is using `ftype: 'grouping'` and `groupHeaderTpl: ...'` to create group rows. I want to make sure when a user clicks on a group row, that all other group rows are collapsed, and this group row is expanded.

According to [this page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Grouping), there is a `groupclick` event that I can subscribe to, and there are methods for `collapseAll()` and `expand()`.

I have managed to subscribe to the `groupclick` event and successfully call the `collapseAll()` method. However, I cannot get the `expand()` method to work.

Here's the issue, the `expand()` method requires me to pass in `groupName`, and I don't know what that actually wants. Inside the `groupclick` event, I have access to a variable called `group`, but that variable is always `undefined`.

My Question: what is the `groupName` that the `expand()` method is asking for, and how do I access it from within the `groupclick` event? Does it need to be defined in the model or the grid somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Here is my controller code:

```
 onGroupClick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {
            console.log(view);
            console.log(node);
            console.log(group) //this is always undefined

            view.features[0].collapseAll(); //works fine
            view.features[0].expand(groupName);  //what goes here for groupName???
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` variable holds group name. So code below should do the job:

```
groupclick: function (view, node, group, e, eOpts) {
    view.features[0].collapseAll(); 
    view.features[0].expand(group);
}
```

If your `group` variable is undefined, probably you have problem with grouping definition. In store you should have defined `groupField` which is name of field from Model (maybe that field is empty for records?).

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/CEJY5/

Comment: hmmm...I must have spelled something wrong yesterday. Today `group` has the correct data in it, and all is working fine.  Thank you for your complete answer. If it wasn't for your jsfiddle example, I wouldn't have believed you :)